# MEAN: Doing database queries in Angular Frontend?

Tags: javascript, database, angular, mongodb, data-manipulation

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to do MongoDB No-SQL Queries (or even SQL-queries for sql database) in the Angular frontend, like formulating the query and then sending the query string to the database and getting a subset of values back (e.g. in JSON-format).

Because the problem that I currently have is, that for each data snippet that I need, I have to create a specific route (e.g for one specific graph) and then do my middleware-function for that route that queries for the data in mongodb (e.g by mongodb aggregation framework). And then finally,  do a http-request in Angular frontend, eventuelly format the data in javascript in angular and then insert the data in correct format into the appropriate charting-framework (e.g ngx-charts).

E.g. If I would like to filter the data in some chart for specific fields, or do some aggregation etc. on the same chart dynamically, I probably would just query all data from beginning, and then create my own (e.g. filter or other data manipulation) functions in javascript for my chart functions.

I heard there are some ways to do this also in the backend, e.g in Node or MongoDB Aggregation framework, there exists $facet operator that can choose some path for data operation, but I actually don't know how this works together with the Frontend...
Is there not a more direct way to query just the data that I need for a specific component without setting up routing and everything else around?